# error when using pip to install Scipy python package on windows

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

While trying to install scipy on windows using the following command in the Command Prompt:

```
pip install scipy
```

I get the following error:

> raise NotFoundError<'no lapack/blas resources found'>
>
> numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources
>   found

After searching the web I've noticed it's a common problem and tried all suggested solutions with no success.
One of the solutions I've tried is installing MinGW for windows...

This is becoming very frustrating... any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to tried to install `scipy` using a Windows installer? like one of these: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.13.2/

Comment: http://scipy.org/install.html

Comment: installing Python(x,y) solved the problem... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the scipy installation guide, you should not use pip for installation on Windows. Rather stick to a binary package provided here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

(link provided as suggested here: https://scipy.org/install.html)

Comment: See also: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1